# Reading & loading HTML file into HTTP response in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, http, server

I'm writing a simple HTTP1.1 server on linux that only hosts one website (root = index.html), and I'm trying to send the HTTP response in a single packet.

I'm trying to find an optimum way to locate and read the html file and then concatenate it into the response buffer.

Note: URL = "/index.html".

First, I have tried the following:

```
    char *root;
    char PATH[9999];

    root = getenv("PWD");
    strcpy(PATH, root); 
    strcpy(&PATH[strlen(root)], URL); 
    int filefd = open(PATH, O_RDONLY);
```

but it's getting me segfault

So I tried this

```
    char *PATH;

    getcwd(PATH, sizeof(PATH));
    strcat(PATH, URL); 
    int filefd = open(PATH, O_RDONLY);
```

But it's also not working.

Note, the way I'm copying the file into the HTTP response is as follows:

```
    char body[fileLen];
    if ( read(filefd, body, fileLen) != -1 ) 
      strcat(response, body);
```

Where fileLen is the length of the index.html file obtained using fseek() and ftell()

Comment: In general, I'd suggest using a debugger or memory analyzer to track down errors like this. On Linux you can use `gdb` and Valgrind, among others. I suspect your `strcat()` is overrunning `response` because `body` is not null-terminated. But why guess when you can debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to send the HTTP response in a single packet

That is never going to work. TCP, by its very nature, is streaming, and will never guarantee a single packet is used. There is no good reason to try to stuff everything into a single buffer. At best, that is a buffer overflow waiting to happen. But right now, you are not even able to get your filename into a properly allocated char buffer to begin with, let alone open the file and read it into a HTTP response buffer.

> ```c
> char *root;
> char PATH[9999];
>
> root = getenv("PWD");
> strcpy(PATH, root); 
> strcpy(&PATH[strlen(root)], URL); 
> int filefd = open(PATH, O_RDONLY);
> ```

This causes a segfault because you are not checking the result of `getenv()` for NULL.  `getenv("PWD")` is not the correct way to get the calling process's current working directory. And it is *undefined behavior* to pass a NULL pointer to `strcpy()` or `strlen()`.

```c
char *root = getenv("PWD");
if (root) {
    char PATH[9999];
    strcpy(PATH, root); 
    strcpy(&PATH[strlen(root)], URL); 
    int filefd = open(PATH, O_RDONLY);
    ...
}
```

> ```c
> char *PATH;
>
> getcwd(PATH, sizeof(PATH));
> strcat(PATH, URL); 
> int filefd = open(PATH, O_RDONLY);
> ```

This fails because you are not allocating any memory for `PATH` to point at so `getpwd()` and `strcat()` have something to write into.  Use a fixed array instead:

```c
char PATH[9999];

if (getcwd(PATH, sizeof(PATH))) {
    strcat(PATH, URL); 
    int filefd = open(PATH, O_RDONLY);
    ...
}
```

> ```c
> char body[fileLen];
> if ( read(filefd, body, fileLen) != -1 ) 
>     strcat(response, body);
> ```

This is also wrong.  `strcat()` requires a null-terminated string to copy from, but the result of `read()` is not null-terminated. `read()` returns the number of bytes it actually read:

```c
char body[fileLen];
int numRead;
if ( (numRead = read(filefd, body, fileLen)) > 0 ) 
    memcpy(&response[strlen(response)], body, numRead);
```

Or:

```c
char body[fileLen];
int numRead = read(filefd, &response[strlen(response)], fileLen);
...
```

Of course, in either case, you would have to make sure that `response` is allocated large enough to actually hold the entire HTTP response headers + file data before calling `read()`.

This is where it starts paying off to utilize the streaming nature of TCP and NOT store the entire HTTP response into a single buffer at all.  Send the HTTP response headers first, and then call `read()` in a loop sending each buffer that is successfully read, eg:

```c
int sendRaw(int sckt, const void *buf, size_t buflen) {
    const char *ptr = (const char*) buf;
    int numSent;
    while ( buflen > 0 ) {
        if ( (numSent = send(sckt, ptr, buflen, 0)) < 0 ) {
            return -1;
        }
        ptr += numSent;
        buflen -= numSent;
    }
    return 0;
}

int sendStr(int sckt, const char *str) {
    return sendStr(sckt, str, strlen(str));
}

...

const char *URL = "/index.html";
char PATH[9999];

if (getcwd(PATH, sizeof(PATH))) {
    strcat(PATH, URL); 
} else {
    PATH[0] = '\0';
}

int filefd = open(PATH, O_RDONLY);
if ( filefd < 0 ) {
    // error handling as needed ...
    sendStr(sckt, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n");
    close(sckt);
    return;
}

fileLen = ...; // get file length as needed ...

if ( dprintf(sckt, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\n\r\n", fileLen) < 0 ) {
    // error handling as needed ...
    close(filefd);
    close(sckt);
    return;
}

char body[1024];
int numRead;

while ( fileLen > 0 ) {
    if ( (numRead = read(filefd, body, min(fileLen, 1024))) <= 0 ) {
        // error handling as needed ...
        close(filefd);
        close(sckt);
        return;
    }

    if ( sendRaw(sckt, body, numRead) < 0 ) {
        // error handling as needed ...
        close(filefd);
        close(sckt);
        return;
    }

    fileLen -= numRead;
}

close(filefd);
...
```